# How to have transition animations when using QML ListView and C++ QList<QObject*>?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I am using QtQuick 2.0 and QML ListView which I connected to my model in C++ (a QList of Objects). The connection was made through QQmlContext::setContextProperty().

Now the documentation told me that there was no direct way for the interface to know about changes so I only actualized the context whenever I changed my model. However when I do so, the view actualizes directly without firing any event (such as add or remove events), which annoys me a bit because I can't have any control over the transitions.

To put it simply here is my qml code:

```
ListView {
id : list
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds

        anchors {
            top: titleBar.bottom
            topMargin: -1
            bottom: mainWindow.bottom
            bottomMargin: -1
        }
        width: mainWindow.width

        model: episodes
        delegate: Episode {
            id: myDelegate
            onShowClicked: episodes.append(episodes[index])
        }

        ScrollBar {
            flickable: list;
        }
    }
```

where Episode is my custom delegate. It contains the following code:

```
ListView.onAdd: SequentialAnimation {
    PropertyAction { target: episodeDelegate; property: "height"; value: 0 }
    NumberAnimation { target: episodeDelegate; property: "height"; to: 80; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }
}

ListView.onRemove: SequentialAnimation {
    PropertyAction { target: episodeDelegate; property: "ListView.delayRemove"; value: true }
    NumberAnimation { target: episodeDelegate; property: "height"; to: 0; duration: 250; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad }

    // Make sure delayRemove is set back to false so that the item can be destroyed
    PropertyAction { target: episodeDelegate; property: "ListView.delayRemove"; value: false }
}
```

which is a direct copy from Qt Examples.

To summarize, the model is correctly linked and synced, though the way of doing so prevents me from knowing the nature of the model changes in my QML logic.

Do anyone know of any trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reset the `setContextProperty`, you can use the `populate` transition. However, this applies the transition to all elements in the list, concurrently.

If you want to have an animation each time you add an item, you could do that using signals. For example:

```
class SomeList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SomeList(QObject *parent = 0);

    void Add(QString color, QString value)
    {
        emit addNew(color,value);
    }

signals:
    void addNew(QString data1,QString data2);
};
```

and in main.cpp you could have:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppInstance",new SomeList);

    return app.exec();
}
```

and in QML:

```
ListModel{
    id:someListModel
}

Rectangle{
    width: 600
    height: 600
    ListView{
        model:someListModel
        delegate:Rectangle{
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height/10
            color: model.color
            Text{
                text: value
            } 
        }
    }
    Connections{
        target: cppInstance
        onAddNew: { someListModel.insert(0,{"color":data1,"value":data2})}
    } 
}
```

In the `SomeList` class, you could also have a `QList` as member, which would contain the strings you insert in QML.

Comment: I'm really out of the subject by now, but I believe your solution does answer my problem at the time. I tried as much as I could to stick to QML only for the display, which is why I didn't have a List Item in C++ but only the view in QML. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: That's a nice solution.

Comment: Didn't see the date you asked the question until now... I stumbled upon your question because a week ago I was having the same problem. Hopefully this answer will help people who are in the same situation like I was.